# When using Unity in Universal app got lots of Warning about Resources

Tags: wpf, unity-container, win-universal-app, universal

I'm writing a windows universal app, when I add Unity to my project by NuGet and build it, many warning about Unity's Resources appear.

Like those:

> No default or neutral resource given for 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Properties.Resources/SettingPropertyOperation'. The application may throw an exception for certain user configurations when retrieving the resources. HJ  C:\Projects\TTT\HJ\HJ\MakePRI
>   No default or neutral resource given for 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Properties.Resources/MustHaveOpenGenericType'. The application may throw an exception for certain user configurations when retrieving the resources.  HJ  C:\Projects\TTT\HJ\HJ\MakePRI
>   ...

In my project there are 50+ warning like this,Shall I ignore them ?
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want these warnings to go away you just need to add the missing resources to the files the warnings are mentioning. Have a look [here](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer/issues/317), somewhat similar. I think you can ignore them if you want, it is just saying it might be a problem or that it cannot guarantee that a particular resource candidate can be returned for that resource identifier at run time. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) for more information.